# Mock instance method of a model class by replacing it with a new method

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, mocking, side-effects

I want to replace the instance method "set_email_id" with a new function in unit tests by mocking. The instance method returns the email_id field but I want a new function to print the same field. I am not sure which mocking feature to use. I read about side_effect, mock.object etc. I couldn't make it work.

Script:

```
class Myclass(models.Model):

   email_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

   def return_email_id(self):
       return self.email_id

def run():
    my_class = Myclass()
    my_class.email_id = 1

    #want to moke this call
    my_class.return_email_id()
```

Unit test:

```
@patch('models.Myclass.return_email_id')
def test(self, mock_email_id):

    def new_method():
        # this should replace the instance method
        print(self.email_id)

    # I know this wouldn't work. I just wanted to show it as an example
    mock_email_id.side_effect = new_method()
```

Comment: If the instance exist for the test only you can just over write it with any callable: `instance.set_email_id = lambda self: …` or a Mock of your choice. And BTW the name of the method is somewhat misleading if you see what it actually does.

Comment: I changed the name of the method. thx. can you elaborate on overwriting the instance? It doesn't exist just for the test. I am basically testing "run()" function and I want "my_class.return_email_id()" to print the email_id field within the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this example.

mook_2.py

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from constants import STATUS_ENDPOINT


class BuildStatus:
    """The CI status of a pull request."""

    @staticmethod
    def build_date() -> str:
        return datetime.utcnow().isoformat()

    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, merge_request_id, status):
        build_status = {
            "id": merge_request_id,
            "status": status,
            "built_at": cls.build_date(),
        }
        response = requests.post(STATUS_ENDPOINT, json=build_status)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response
```

test_mook.py

```
from unittest import mock

from constants import STATUS_ENDPOINT
from mock_2 import BuildStatus


@mock.patch("mock_2.requests") # mock_2.requests를 호출하면 mock_requests 모의 객체가 대신할것
def test_build_notification_sent(mock_requests):
    build_date = "2018-01-01T00:00:01"
    with mock.patch("mock_2.BuildStatus.build_date", return_value=build_date): # build_date 호출시 설정한 날짜 반환하도록함,
        BuildStatus.notify(123, "OK")

    expected_payload = {"id": 123, "status": "OK", "built_at": build_date}
    mock_requests.post.assert_called_with(
        STATUS_ENDPOINT, json=expected_payload
    )
```

constants.py

```
"""Definitions"""

STATUS_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/mrstatus"
```